# Android проект не хочет компилироваться!

Tags: android

Скачиваю проект, запускаю, а билдить его `Gradle` не хочет, жалуется (см.скриншот). В общем, что делать - не знаю, Gradle до последней версии обновлял, тоже не хочет работать, [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Вот ссылка на этот [проект](https://github.com/unrarp/material-calculator).

Comment: нажмите на ссылку и студия все сделает за вас

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше выкладывать в виде текста а не картинок

Comment: я нажимал, ничего не происходит

Comment: вручную измените версию Gradle До 2.6 и сделайте Sync

Comment: пытался, не работает, можете сами проверить :)

Comment: Сами поглядите:

Comment: До изменения Gradle до 2.6: 10:52 PM Gradle sync failed: Support for builds using Gradle versions older than 2.6 was removed in tooling API version 5.0. You are currently using Gradle version 2.2.1. You should upgrade your Gradle build to use Gradle 2.6 or later.
     Possible solution:
     - Upgrade Gradle wrapper to 2.6 version and re-import the project
     Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (1 s 161 ms)

Comment: После: 10:54 PM Gradle sync failed: Unsupported method: BaseConfig.getApplicationIdSuffix().
     The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
     To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
     Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.
     Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (28 s 561 ms)

Comment: А вы уверены, что этот проект вам вообще нужен? Если вы хотите собрать приложение с поддержкой Андроид 2.3.3, то как минимум должны установить все SDK-компоненты, обозначенные в gradle-файлах и именно те версии. Но возможно ещё и студию тех времён поставить придётся. Теперь спрошу ещё раз: вам действительно нужен стоковый калькулятор из Андроид 5.0, адаптированный для установки на более старые версии системы?

Comment: мне не нужен калькулятор, я хотел глянуть как они реализовали там выдвижную панель, сбоку которая, а именно как они "ручку" сделали, за которую юзер вытягивает эту панель :)